# Two symfony routes with same url?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, routes

Is it possible two have to symfony routes (sfDoctrineRoute) with same url ( /:sf_culture/:slug/), but different model?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own Route class, extending sfObjectRoute. Have you take a look at the code of sfDoctrineRoute ? It's not that complicated.

Rewrite getObjectForParameters() to search on both models, set the "class" parameter in routing, maybe add an option "models" and you are done.

sfDoctrineRouteCollection is not able to search on multiple Models.

Answer (score 0):

The first URL match is the route that will be used.  You need to differentiate the URLs in some way for each route.

You should explore using sfDoctrineRouteCollection instead.